# Returning Null When Fetching API Asynchronously Before Data Fetches

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**My Attempt**

I'm attempting to fetch an API multiple times and put the data into a table. As a result, I'm calling an API several times. I'm trying to make it so if the data for a certain year is there, it fills a table, but if not, nothing is shown. If the data is there for all years, it loads and fills in the table just fine, but if not it breaks. Here's what I'm working with.

**MAIN.JS**

```
 <table>
     <thead>
             <tr>
                    <th>Season</th>
                     <th>GP</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <SkaterTableStats season={currentSeason} id={props.id} />
                         <SkaterTableStats season={prevSeason} id={props.id} />
                 </tbody>
             </table>
```

**SKATERTABLESTATS.JS**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function SkaterTableStats(props) {

    const [playerStat, setPlayerStat] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
    getInfoData();

async function getInfoData() {
    const statx = await fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${props.id}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=${props.season}`)
    .then(response => response.json());
    setPlayerStat(statx);
    }
}, []);


if (playerStat) { 
return (
    <tr>
    <td>{playerStat.stats[0].splits[0].season}</td>
    <td>{playerStat.stats[0].splits[0].stat.games}</td> 
</tr>    
)} else {
    return (null)
  }
}

export default SkaterTableStats
```

Unfortunately, when loading the API, it always brings up *something*, which is usually the sport's copywrite et al, but no stats.

**What Usually Happens**

-Calls Data

-If the player has played x amount of years, data fills no problem

-If player hasn't played x amount of years, data fills until it gets to that year, and then breaks, saying playerStat.statsEtc is undefined. I want it to return nothing.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried putting an if statement in the return statement, a la:

```
if (playerStat) {
return (
etc
) 
}
```

But because it's async, it loads that before the data loads, and breaks. Same for:

```
if (!playerStat.stats[0].splits[0].stat.timeOnIce > 0) {
return etc
```

&

```
if (playerStat == undefined) {
return etc
```

But neither have worked.
I would have liked to put the returning data into a table but the table is formatted oddly and React requires whatever returns to be in one enclosing div, which in this case is the . But if I put another div or anything similar it breaks the tables and places all the info in the one column.

Any help is appreciated, and I will happily clarify anything that needs clarifying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to not use both async/await and then/catch.

Try to change your function to use then/catch only, so simply put that in useEffect with empty dep array

```
 fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${props.id}/statsstats=statsSingleSeason&season=${props.season}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => setPlayerStat(response);
```

maybe put some consolelogs in .then(), try to figure out what is the answer you're getting, try rebuilding it back to use async/await only and check what happens there.

Check props you're getting, maybe there is something wrong? Feel free to provide further info if the above won't work.

Also try to not call functions before their declarations :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the async/await/then/catch area that's the problem, as the entire code works when the data I'm calling contains the years I'm looking for. Same for the props. When the data is there, it's getting fetched just fine, but if not, it breaks before it can return null. I will fix the calling functions part though, thank you.

Comment: I also suggest to add .catch blocks to your code to handle exactly those problems, where no data is returned. Add some placeholder as initial state for playerStat value instead of null and add if statements in jsx. What you did ()if return else return) is not too good. better write if(!playerStat) return null; and then just the rest of code, no else is needed here, trust me it would look much more clean. async/then syntax is not incorrect so it won't break your app, but it simply makes no sense to use both at once :) Provide some example requests/responses and maybe I could help more!

Comment: I recognize that the if return else return is awkward & bad practice, but I'm not sure how else to do it, since the returning data has to have one enclosing tag. Ex: I've done both return ( <tr> {if (!playerStat) return null) but then the actual data that does get through needs a tag to enclose in that. I can't put a tag around that though, because it messes up the table format. I've also tried return ( if (!playerStat) return null) <tr></tr>) but that also fails because the if statement can't be outside a tag. I need to put a tag before & after the if statement, but doing so breaks table form

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do so :) ---if(!data) return null; return <tr></tr>---  ----return <>{data ? <tr></tr> : null}</>---- ----return <>{data && <tr></tr>}</>

Comment: I'm sorry, it did not work. It still returns as the data is undefined and then breaks. I wish I could show it to someone as it's too complicated to really show why it isn't working. It's incredibly frustrating....

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you further without any more informations. Request looks fine, if the props are too I might be missing something in your question. Try to provide specific expected/actual values in the question itself + example props where request is correct, and where it's not

Comment: I appreciate the help majkel. I think I'm going to just blow it all up and quit. I'm upvoting your response because I appreciate the time you took to respond. I'm just so incredibly frustrated by it, I'm done.